# Convert a segment of an Hex string to a double

Tags: ios, objective-c, hex, double, strtol

I have a device that returns data as a Hex value, for example `00 00 00 56 00 00 01 00`. I place this into an NSString. I am only interested in converting the 3rd and 4th segment to a double. ie only `00 56`.

On sites such as http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter it works and returns me the value I want.

When I try to use NSScanner it doesn't like that it is only a segment of a Hex code.

```
NSScanner *scanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:numberAsHex];

double value = 0.0;

BOOL result = [scanner scanHexDouble:&value];

NSLog(@"Value %@", [NSNumber numberWithDouble:value]);
NSLog(@"Result %c", result);
```

I have also tried to use `strtol()` as well but no luck.

Could anyone help?

Comment: The Result at the moment returns 0.000

Comment: you want this `369367187712` from this string `@"0000005600000100` ?

Comment: Does this "device" use the same *endianness* as the iPhone/iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That string for NSScanner should be like this.
Here is a sample code (It works.)

```
NSScanner *scanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:@"0x0056"];
double value = 0;
BOOL result = [scanner scanHexDouble:&value];

NSLog(@"Value %@", [NSNumber numberWithDouble:value]);
NSLog(@"Result %c", result);
```

Comment: You should seperate that hexstring to convert

Comment: This worked, all I had to do was strip the spaces away and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *numberAsHex = @"00 00 00 56 00 00 01 00";
numberAsHex = [numberAsHex stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
numberAsHex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"0x",numberAsHex];
NSScanner *scanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:numberAsHex];
double value = 0.0;
BOOL result = [scanner scanHexDouble:&value];
NSLog(@"Value %@", [NSNumber numberWithDouble:value]);
NSLog(@"Result %d", result);
```